# Beamer title font color

Tags: beamer, color, titles

I would like to use the title color of my `beamer` presentation (some kind of blue) to write some inline text with the same color. Therefore I want to know the color definition. Is there a command for using the same color as the title?

My preamble definitions are:

```
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
}
\usecolortheme{crane}
```

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{caption}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
}
\usecolortheme{crane}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{\bf This is the title's color I want to ``copy''}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 
            I want to use the ``blue'' color from the title for the caption of the table.
        \end{itemize}
        \vspace{1.5\baselineskip}

        \begin{table}
            \begin{tabular}{c|c}
                table1 & trial \\
                \hline
                \hline
                1 & 2 \\
                3 & 4
            \end{tabular}
            \caption*{My table}
        \end{table}     
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean presentation title or frame title color? Could you post a compilable minimal example? Only with theme Warsaw and crane color theme there's no title with some kind of blue color.

Comment: I added some code to clarify what I mean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can copy the color from the frame title this way:

```
\caption*{\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}{My table}}
```

Answer (score 8):

The command `\usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}` (see p. 186 http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) should provide you with the (text) color used in the header, even if you later decide to change your theme or change the title text color yourself in the preamble.

Comment: +1 Just tried your solution with the OPs MWE, it works too.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct, though I didn't use this solution correctly at first

Comment: @Elec If you think the solution is good, you can also upvote it, by clicking the arrow on the left side of the answer. This general site feature helps further readers finding correct and good posts.

Comment: @Elec It would be good, if you would register on this site. Then you can also vote for the answers to your questions and you have further access to site features.